# Unable find printf.c on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I recently switched to the `Ubuntu 16.04`. I am using `vscode` for as IDE on Ubuntu. I configure other languages, but I could not do it for `C/C++`. I created `c_cpp_properties.json, launch.json & tasks.json`. When I started to compile the any given code, It gives an error when the fit functions like `printf` or `malloc`. 
The Error message:

> Unable to open 'printf.c': File not found (file:///build/glibc-Cl5G7W/glibc-2.23/stdio-common/printf.c).

How can I fix the problem?

*launch.json*

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "build"
    }
]
}
```

*tasks.json*

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "gcc",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "pointer_revision.c",
            "-o",
            "test.exe"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

*c_cpp_properties.json*

```
{
      "configurations": {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
            "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed",
            "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
            "/usr/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
               "${workspaceFolder}",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        },
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc"
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a feature, not a bug. Literally! They said it is "by design" here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1123

Comment: *"It gives an error when the fit functions like printf or malloc."*, what does this mean?

Comment: There is a typo mistake. Its not fit, it will be hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian and Ubuntu do not ship sources as part of the debugging packages unfortunately.  As far I can tell, there is no plan to ship sources as part of [dbgsym packages](https://wiki.debian.org/DebugPackage), either.

In contrast, Fedora and its downstream distributions have extensive infrastructure to prepare usable source files for debugging.  It is not entirely trivial to do this because it requires rewriting file paths in the DWARF data, from the build tree location to the installation location.  But it can be really helpful for debugging and gives a nice free software flavor to the entire distribution.

Comment: I switched from windows 10. I did not want use Windows anymore. It's pretty new Linux environment for me

Comment: Ah. I don't think Ubuntu is the right choice if you want to step into system libraries with source code, I'm afraid. There are certainly other reasons for choosing this distribution, but sourceful debugging is not one of them.

Comment: I switched Ubuntu 16.04 to Manjaro KDE. I am very happy right now. It works perfectly with VScode. I can debug without any problem. Best distro i have ever used